# Android Custom AutoComplete textview icon and text

Tags: android, autocomplete

I want to have an `AutoCompleteTextView` that can display both text and icon. I get help from this example: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

In this example, images are used in drawable folder of the project. But, I want to use images from the database. I do not know how to change the second parameter below code to put the image from database instead of drawable folder's image.

**Update:**
It turns out that I need to use a custom adopter. I have tried the below code, but getView is not being called. Why?

**SearchItemArrayAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryEntry>
{
    private static final String tag = "SearchItemArrayAdapter";
    private CountryEntry listEntry;
    private TextView autoItem;
    private ImageView categoryIcon;
    private List<CountryEntry> countryEntryList = new ArrayList<CountryEntry>();

    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public SearchItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CountryEntry> objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        countryEntryList = objects;
        Log.d(tag, "Search List -> journalEntryList := " + countryEntryList.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        Log.w(tag, "Size:= " +  this.countryEntryList.size());
        return this.countryEntryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CountryEntry getItem(int position)
    {
        CountryEntry journalEntry = this.countryEntryList.get(position);
        Log.d(tag, "*-> Retrieving JournalEntry @ position: " + String.valueOf(position) + " : " + journalEntry.toString());
        //return journalEntry;
        return countryEntryList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Log.w(tag, "GetView");

        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_layout, parent, false);
        }

        listEntry = this.countryEntryList.get(position);
        String searchItem = listEntry.title;
        autoItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        autoItem.setText(searchItem);

        // Get a reference to ImageView holder
        categoryIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        categoryIcon.setImageBitmap(listEntry.image);



        return row;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    AutoCompleteTextView mAutoCompleteTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // Add the country details

        AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);

        ArrayList<CountryEntry> list = new ArrayList<CountryEntry>();

        // Add it to array
        list.add(new CountryEntry("india", theImage));
        list.add(new CountryEntry("usa", theImage));

        SearchItemArrayAdapter adapter = new SearchItemArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, list);

        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**CountryEntry**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
public class CountryEntry {
    public String title;
    public Bitmap image;

    public CountryEntry(String title, Bitmap image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="autocomplete"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_currency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/autocomplete"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**autocomplete_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
     >

    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:padding="10dp"
    />

    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:padding="10dp"          
    />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you [checked this](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=CAD52F00EA0265C80BDD218165CDDA26?recipeId=827&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) ??

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, I checked it. But, not sure about this line iconRetriever = new CategoryIconRetriever(context); Any idea?

Comment: You can remove this `iconRetriever.getJournalEntryTypeIcon(journalEntry.typeId))` and put your code of setting Image in ImageView

Answer (score 4):

[This link](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=CAD52F00EA0265C80BDD218165CDDA26?recipeId=827&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) is great, but it's missing one critical thing - in order for the adapter to successfully show the correct auto-completions for your typed-in text,
your "JournalEntry" (as in the example link) must implement its own toString() for the filtering:

```
public class JournalEntry {
    public String title;
    public Bitmap image;

    public String toString() {
        return this.title.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this link](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=CAD52F00EA0265C80BDD218165CDDA26?recipeId=827&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) to fulfill your requirement :

Your class :

```
public class ConutryEntry {
    public String title;
    public Bitmap image;

}
```

The Adapter :

```
 public class SearchItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryEntry>
    {
        private static final String tag = "SearchItemArrayAdapter";
        private CountryEntry listEntry;
        private TextView autoItem;
        private ImageView categoryIcon;
        private List<CountryEntry> countryEntryList = new ArrayList<CountryEntry>();

        /**
         * 
         * @param context
         * @param textViewResourceId
         * @param objects
         */
        public SearchItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<CountryEntry> objects)
            {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                countryEntryList = objects;
                Log.d(tag, "Search List -> journalEntryList := " + countryEntryList.toString());
            }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
            {
                return this.countryEntryList.size();
            }

        @Override
        public CountryEntry getItem(int position)
            {
                CountryEntry journalEntry = this.countryEntryList.get(position);
                Log.d(tag, "*-> Retrieving JournalEntry @ position: " + String.valueOf(position) + " : " + journalEntry.toString());
                return journalEntry;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View row = convertView;
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

                if (row == null)
                    {
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_listitem_icon, parent, false);
                    }

                listEntry = this.countryEntryList.get(position);
                String searchItem = listEntry.title;
                autoItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.search_auto_item);
                autoItem.setText(searchItem);

                // Get a reference to ImageView holder
                categoryIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
                categoryIcon.setImageBitmap(listEntry.image);

                return row;
            }
    }
```

Fill the Array like:

```
        byte Pic[];
        Pic = yourImageByte; //get the image in the form of byte[] from db
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Pic);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

        // Add the country details

        CountryEntry entry= new CountryEntry();
        entry.title = "India";
        entry.image = theImage;

        // Add it to array
        list.add(entry);
        SearchItemArrayAdapter adapter = new SearchItemArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.search_bar_fragment, list);
```

Comment: I could not make it work, can you check what is wrong? http://pastebin.com/DMHKci7w

Comment: I have updated the question to show you what i have done, can you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

This is the UI thread code

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> detailsFromDB = GET THIS FROM DB;

....

String[] from = {"item_picture","item_name"};
    // Ids of views in listview_layout
int[] to = {R.id.image, R.id.nametext};
if(names != null){
    AutoCompleteSimpleAdapter autoSimpleAdapter = new AutoCompleteSimpleAdapter(getActivity(), detailsFromDB , R.layout.auto_complete_select_item, from, to);
    [AUTO_COMPLETE_VIEW].setAdapter(autoSimpleAdapter );
}
```

Adapter code:

```
public class AutoCompleteSimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private int[] mTo;
    private String[] mFrom;
    private ViewBinder mViewBinder;

    private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> mData;

    private int mResource;
    private int mDropDownResource;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private SimpleFilter mFilter;
    private ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> mUnfilteredData;

    public AutoCompleteSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        mData = data;
        mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
         return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
    }

    private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        bindView(position, v);

        return v;
    }

    public void setDropDownViewResource(int resource) {
        this.mDropDownResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mDropDownResource);
    }

    private void bindView(int position, View view) {
        final Map<String, ?> dataSet = mData.get(position);
        if (dataSet == null) {
            return;
        }

        final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
        final String[] from = mFrom;
        final int[] to = mTo;
        final int count = to.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
                String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
                if (text == null) {
                    text = "";
                }

                boolean bound = false;
                if (binder != null) {
                    bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
                }

                if (!bound) {
                    if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                        if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                            ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                            // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                            // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                            setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                                    " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                                    (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                        }
                    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                        // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                        // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                        setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {

                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(((String) data).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        setViewImage((ImageView)v, bitmap);
                       /* if (data instanceof Integer) {
                            setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);                            
                        } else {
                            setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                        }*/
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                                " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewBinder getViewBinder() {
        return mViewBinder;
    }

    public void setViewBinder(ViewBinder viewBinder) {
        mViewBinder = viewBinder;
    }

    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, int value) {
        v.setImageResource(value);
    }

    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, Bitmap bitmap) {
        v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
        try {
            v.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            v.setImageURI(Uri.parse(value));
        }
    }

    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        v.setText(text);
    }

    public static interface ViewBinder {
        boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation);
    }



}
```